# Connection to a site made by Http Post - how to check if connection is still alive?

Tags: http, cookies, web-scraping, dart, web-crawler

I'm developing a **Scraping** app to extract some information from a sit. To get that information I have to be logged in to that site.

So I use Http post and pass the data needed for login using FormData and log in successfully, so I can browse the private content of that site.

My question Is: "How can I tell if the user is logged in?". What is the simple way to do that using session cookies or something like that?

I'm currently checking the connection by sending an Http Get Request to a Url that I know is available to registered users.

So before I try to login again, I use this method "isLoggedIn" to check the connection. But it is not perfect, I mean, it seems a kind o tricky and not the best way to do that.

Currently, I'm using Dio - a Lib to make Http Request in Dart. But I think it's a general Http matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to register...

I solve that after checking the difference between a 'logged' and a 'not logged in' response. In my specify case, when I did a get request to the login page, it answers with a response that has a 'CUSTOMER_AUTH' cookie setted with a random String, otherwise, this cookie is not present.

So I just check if this cookie is present and if it has a valid value.